# ASP.NET MVC: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I added to my user a new field: "Name" (because I saw UserName had the same value as the email, so I didn't want to change it). I cannot register a new user with Facebook, for a reason. The line that brings the error is "result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(useraux.Id, info.Login);" in ExternalLoginConfirmation, so I thought user.Id maybe has no value before inserting all the user info into the user table, so I waited after the user is put in the table, then I select it by email to get its id, but it still gives me the error. I think I broke my external login when I requested from Facebook more data (the name of the user); for that I had to bring some changes to the code. I added to ExternalLoginCallback the following line to get firstname: "var firstName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:first_name").Value;"

My code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Name, Email = model.Email , Name = model.Name};
        
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var useraux = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(useraux.Id, info.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //--
                //await StoreFacebookAuthToken(user);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}
```

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    var firstName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:first_name").Value;
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email, Name = firstName });
    }
}
```

***Edit:*** I added the line that brings the error in a try-catch block, that should write to the console the error like this "Console.WriteLine("Entity of type "{0}" in state "{1}" has the following validation errors:",", were exactly should I look? There is nothing in the console that opens by right-click and "inspect", and there is nothing in Visual Studio. However, it somehow solved my problem and I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: "See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details" - did take a look at the `EntityValidationErrors` collection on the exception? If not, why not?

Comment: The exception is being thrown from Entity Framework and it has nothing to do with Claims or Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

### **use `DbEntityValidationException` for see error details**

```cs
try
{
    //...

    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);

    //...
}
catch(DbEntityValidationException ex) 
{
    foreach (var err in ex.ValidationErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```